# Python/Selenium cannot find all the elements, just some

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I try to get informations from the following page: https://www.spar.hu/onlineshop/haztartas-es-szabadido/papiraru/toalettpapir/c/H12-1-2/

I need the name of the item, the price and the unit price, for each.

When I run my code, it gets back only 6 from the 36 items.

Can someone help me with this? Im a total beginner in Python, so any advice is welcome!

Also I tried to go through the pages, that also didnt work. If someone has a solution for that also, that would be great.

Thank you!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import requests
from csv import writer
from datetime import date
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
url = "https://www.spar.hu/onlineshop/haztartas-es-szabadido/wc-furdoszoba/toalettpapir/c/H12-3-1/"

driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
webdriver.Chrome().get_cookies()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)


with open('Spar Toalett papír.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    header = ['Termék', 'Termék ár', 'Egységár']
    thewriter.writerow(header)


    for i in range(1):
        driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        items = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,   'productBox')))
        items = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "productBoxTop.cf.j-toggleProductInfo")
        print(len(items))
        
        driver.implicitly_wait(50)
        for item in items:
            driver.implicitly_wait(50)
            
            name = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'productTitle').text
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,100);")
            price = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'priceInteger').text
            unit = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'extraInfoPrice').text
            #info = [id, datetoday, Sorszam, bolt, name, price]
            thewriter.writerow(info)
            print(sorszam, name, price, unit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found what is the problem. When the site is opens, pop-ups also open to accept cookies. If I manually accept cookies and close all pop-ups all the datas are found.